# Display JsonArray from api and sort

Tags: android, json, hashmap, retrofit

I am trying to display data from a rest api containing a Json Array and a list of Json objects. I tried following a tutorial and was able to display the data on textview. What I actually want to do is gather the data in a Hashmap in terms of key and value pair and sort them accordingly.

```
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                textView.setText("Code: " +response.code());
                return;
            }

            int j=0;
            List<Post> posts = response.body();
            Map<Integer,String> data = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

   // Iterating through post and saving data in content variable

           for(Post post: posts)
            {
                String content ="";
                //String name = post.getName();
                if(!(post.getName()==(null)) && !(post.getName().equals("")))
                {
                    data.put(post.getListid(),post.getName()); //For inserting data into hashmap
                    content += "ListID: " + post.getListid() + "" + "\n";
                    content += "Name: " + post.getName() + "" + "\n";
                }


                textView.append(content);

            }
```

The current code saves the data in a content variable and displays it in the text view.

I am relatively new to using hashmap and retrofit for displaying data. I would really appreciate if someone could explain me where I am going wrong with my code. I tried printing out the data but was only able to print the last line and not the rest.

This is my Json file that I want to sort and display the data

```
[{"listId":2,"name":null},{"listId":2,"name":"Item 990"},{"listId":2,"name":null},{"listId":2,"name":null},{"listId":2,"name":""},{"listId":4,"name":"Item 771"},{"listId":2,"name":""}]
```

This is the code that I am using to displaying all my json data in textview

```
for(Map.Entry entry: data.entrySet())
           {  textView.append(entry.getKey()+ "  Value:" +entry.getValue() +"\n");}
```

Answer (score 0):

I if understand correctly, you have a `List<Post> posts` that you want to sort out ? Why don't you sort the `posts` as you need and save them accordingly? You could just remove the `post` from your list if their name are `null` or `""`

Comment: The data that I have in post is both listid and name as shown in the JSON. What I want to do exactly is present the data in a recycler view with the main heading as List id and sub content as items. I am actually trying this out for the first time and I am confused with it

Comment: I can only recommend you to follow [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) or [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k).
You should start a new project while following these tutorial and once you've grasped everything apply it to your project.